# Trigger mousewheel to scroll left to right on desktop and top to bottom on window width below 768px

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, resize

I'm trying to trigger the mousewheel to scroll left to right on desktop and top to bottom on window width below 768px.

This is what I've got so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if( $(this).width() > 768 ) {
    $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    }
$(window).resize(function() {
        if( $(this).width() > 768 ) {
    $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    }
  });
});
```

Works fine when page loads but doesn't change when resized, so I guess there's something up with the resize part of the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a function and then running that function each time on resize:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function mouseScroll(){
        $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
        mouseScroll();
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
            mouseScroll();
        }
    });

});
```